# Using NSOutlineView with NSTreeController in MonoMac

Tags: nsoutlineview, monomac

Anyone got an example on how to use NSOutlineView with NSTreeController bindings using MonoMac?

Thanks in advance,
Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

MonoMac includes an example for NSOutlineView called "macdoc". Unfortunately it just shows you how to use the control with text nodes.

Currently I'm trying to implement a sidebar with icons and text. But unfortunately up to now I didn't manage to implement the "view based" content model (needed for images and text as nodes).

If needed I can provide my running program with text nodes.